# Why does this work: if ( isset($var) && $var ){

Tags: php

Lets say I have a variable $var that has not been defined. Why don't I get errors with this statement:

```
if ( isset($var) && $var ){
    // something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

How can you check whether something is true or not "&& $var" if it is not set yet? Does isset() do something to the if statement. Surely this should return:

```
Notice: Undefined variable:$var
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When the first part of the if statement fails, the rest of it is not evaluated, since the entire statement can not be true. Only if the `isset` part is true, does the execution reach your $var statement.

This is a standard language feature and is common to most programming languages.

It is called "Short Circuit Evaluation", and you can learn more about it on Wikipedia here : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: To add to what rikh said: notices don't really matter. It'd be much more readable to just have if($var). It will perform identically (because null evaluates to false).

Comment: It is called [Short Circuit Evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Answer (score 2):

It's because of [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

That means if the first parameters for `&&` operator is false there's no need to evaluate the second parameter.

Answer (score 1):

This is because when `isset()` returns `false`, the rest of the if statement is not evaluated. The order in which the 2 parts of the if statement are entered is so that your code works. Have you tried turning around the if statement like so:

```
if ($var && isset($var))
{
  // something
}
```

This should fail.

Answer (score 1):

&& is a [short-circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_evaluation) operator.  That means that the rest of the expression will not be processed if the first half of the expression returns false.  Because of this, $var is never process to see if it's defined or not.

Answer (score 1):

Other have already pointed out, that the `&&` operator is lazy. But there is another point to this question:

If a variable is not defined in PHP, the interpreter treats it, as if it had the value `null`. PHP doesn't really care. And as `null` itself is handled as boolean `false`, the above becomes a valid (boolean) expression.

```
<?php

  if( $var ) {
     echo "something";
  } else {
     echo "nothing";
  }
```

will not raise an exception, but simply echo `nothing` if `$var` is not defined.

Comment: While this is true, it is always better to treat warnings as errors

Comment: @vava: Yes, that is certainly true. I don't think that the behaviour explained above is a point of glory for the PHP language, and certainly nothing to be exploited on a regular basis...

Comment: why is the && operator lazy? How do you check if two parameters are true? Nested 'if' statements?

Comment: @ed209, let's look at $a && $b expression. If $a is false, all the expression will be false whatever value $b has, so there's no point in evaluating it. But if $a is true, we have to check what value $b has. That's how it works. if ($a && $b) checks if both parameters are true. ($a || $b) checks if any one of the parameters is true in the same lazy fashion. Why - because it is convenient and fast :)

Answer (score 0):

The && operator is short-circuiting. This means that in an expression like `a && b`, b will not be evaluated if a is false. Thus in your example when `isset($var)` is false, the `&& $var`part is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

It s a common interpreter/compiler optimisation with a `&&` (and) the expression will be evaluated until one part of the expression if false. With a `||` (or) the expression will be evaluated until one part is true.

Remember that:

```
false && ?? => false
true && true => true
true && false => false

true || ?? => true
false || true => true
false || false => false
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP (and lots of other languages), the logical operators use [short circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). That means, if the result of an expression is already determined after evaluating a part of the expression, then the rest won't be evaluated anymore.

In your example `isset($var)` returns false. Since the `&&` operator is defined such that it is true only if *all* of its sub-expressions are true, this means that it cannot be true if the left sub-expression is false. Therefore, the right sub-expression won't be evaluated (and does not trigger an error).

Short circuit evaluation is very useful because you can combine a sub-expression that would lead to a runtime error with another one that guarantees that this doesn't happen. An example is the one that you have given. Other languages often use a similar construct for *null-save* constructs, e.g. `if (foo != null && foo.bar == 1)` in Java or C# - `foo.bar` would cause an exception if foo were null, but the virtues of short circuit evaluation guarantee that this will never be evaluated.